# Tkinter Checkbutton: getting the variable for multiple objects

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I want this to create a bunch of Checkboxes on the fly, and when the 'Submit' button is pressed, to look for all checked boxes. Currently, when pressing 'Submit' to call `select_adgroup()`, it prints `0` for every item whether they're checked or not, unless every box is checked, in which case it prints `1` for every item. But I want it to only print `1` for the boxes that are checked.

```
def search_adgroups(self):
    self.adgroups = adgroup(checkBoxVal.get())
    self.inc1 = 1
    self.cbuts1 = []
    for index, item in enumerate(self.adgroups):
    self.adBoxVal = IntVar()
        self.adgroup_check = (Checkbutton(self, variable=self.adBoxVal, text = item))
        self.cbuts1.append(self.adgroup_check)
        self.cbuts1[index].grid(row=self.inc1, sticky=W)
        self.inc1 += 1
    self.button2 = Button(self, text="Submit", command=self.select_adgroup)
    self.button2.grid(row=self.inc1, sticky=W)

def select_adgroup(self):
    for item in self.cbuts1:
        print(self.adBoxVal.get())
```

Comment: What does adgroup do in `adgroup(checkBoxVal.get())`? Can you post complet code? If not, than minimal working version of it would be useful demonstrating the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all it's not `if all checked`, but `if last one checked` it will print 1s. So overall it is only printing last item's value. Which says a lot about the problem.

After `for` loop, `self.adBoxVal`'s value will be the last one so when you try to get its value in your method with `self.adBoxVal.get()`, you only get the last ones value.

To get over this problem, you need to store all `self.adBoxVal`s in a list, then iterate over it.

```
def search_adgroups(self):
    ...
    ...
    self.chks = [] #your list for IntVars
    for index, item in enumerate(self.adgroups):
        adBoxVal = IntVar() #no need self here as BryanOakley points out
        self.chks.append(self.adBoxVal)
        #no need self at below also
        adgroup_check = Checkbutton(self.root, variable=adBoxVal, text = item) 
        self.cbuts1.append(adgroup_check)
        self.cbuts1[index].grid(row=self.inc1, sticky=W)
        self.inc1 += 1
    self.button2 = Button(self.root, text="Submit", command=self.select_adgroup)
    self.button2.grid(row=self.inc1, sticky=W)

def select_adgroup(self):
    for item in self.chks: #here you need to iterate over IntVars
                           #to get thier value
        print (item.get())
```

Also for your future questions, it will be nice if you post a *working* code that reproduces error without some unknown functions or variables.

**EDIT:** Let's use `print`'s to make it clear. When you add `print(self.addBoxVal)` under `self.adBoxVal = IntVar()` you will see every item is different than eachother.

```
    for index, item in enumerate(self.adgroups):
        adBoxVal = IntVar()
        print (adBoxVal)
        >>> 
        PY_VAR0  #I assigned range(5) to adgroups that's why 
        PY_VAR1  #there are 5 elements here
        PY_VAR2
        PY_VAR3
        PY_VAR4
```

If you add `print (adBoxVal)` in `select_adgroup` method in *your* code, you will see it is `PY_VARX`(last one) and code only works with/on that. Since you get [Variable Classes'](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) value(IntVar in your case) by using `.get()` method, you need different ones. Hence you need to save each element in a list, then iterate over it.

Comment: Thanks, your solution worked. Although I don't understand why. When I called self.adBoxVal.get() it will get the value from the last item in the list? Posting working code isn't an option in this case.

Comment: There's also no point in using `self` in front of `self.adBoxVal` and `self.adgroup_check` Since you overwrite those on each iteration of the loop.